# Extract strings with numbers and alphabets in PostgreSQL 11.0

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have following table in PostgreSQL 11.0

```
col1     col2
1        L01XC Monoclonal antibodies
2        S01FB
3        A01AC | C05AA | D07AB | D10AA | H02AB | R01AD | R03BA | R07AX | S01BA | S02BA | S03BA
4        A01AC Corticosteroids for local oral treatment; H02AB Glucocorticoids
```

I have to fetch substrings such that I only get the strings with letters and numbers (concatenate by '|' if multiple existence of codes in a string like ROW 4). Below is the desired output.

```
col1    col2
1       L01XC
2       S01FB
3       A01AC | C05AA | D07AB | D10AA | H02AB | R01AD | R03BA | R07AX | S01BA | S02BA | S03BA
4       A01AC | H02AB
```

I have tried following query:

```
 select distinct  
        regexp_matches(col2, '(?:[A-Z]+\d|\d+[A-Z])[A-Z0-9]*','g') as col2
      from tbl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to groups the results of regexp:

```
select col1, string_agg(v[1], '|') 
 from tbl, 
      regexp_matches(col2, '(?:[A-Z]+\d|\d+[A-Z])[A-Z0-9]*','g') r(v) 
 group by col1 
 order by col1;

┌──────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ col1 │                      string_agg                       │
╞══════╪═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│    1 │ L01XC                                                 │
│    2 │ S01FB                                                 │
│    3 │ A01AC|C05AA|D07AB|D10AA|H02AB|R01AD|R03BA|R07AX|S01BA │
│    4 │ A01AC|H02AB                                           │
└──────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(4 rows)
```